# How to uniformly interface different datatypes in C++

Tags: c++, oop, interface, abstraction

say I have two different frameworks which handle the same resource differently: one framework uses INT as a descriptor while the other encapsulates the resource in a class.

How to design an abstraction layer on top of these frameworks which will actually hide this difference behind a common interface?

Comment: It a good practice to hide third party dependency behind some class/interface (it is easier to replace dependency). In c++ It can be a class or abstract class (interface) or ... . All depends or functionality library delivers and requirements (like performance trade offs). Please provide more details since now topic is to general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the interface you want to use, and provide an [adapter pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) for the other. You wrap a class (or data type) in a new class to alter the interface so that its' compatible with your other classes.

Or, you could look into the [facade pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) in case that suits your needs better. You create a "front-end" class that knows how to reach out to loosely connected interfaces and interacts with them for you. I really like the example provided of calling a customer service line that will then connect you to the appropriate department.

You might even use the adapter in conjunction with the facade to simplify the facade's code.

If the types were similar enough, you could get away with using [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) along with some SFINAE. An example can be found here:*
https://gitlab.com/sweenish/seeded_prng/blob/master/Random.hpp
Code:

```cpp
#ifndef THIS___RANDOM_HPP
#define THIS___RANDOM_HPP

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

namespace rnd {
template <typename T = std::uint32_t, typename Enable = void>
class Mersenne;

template <typename T>
using AllowForUnsigned = std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned_v<T>>;

template <typename T>
class Mersenne<T, AllowForUnsigned<T>>
{
public:
    Mersenne();
    T operator()();

    using result_type = T;
    static constexpr result_type min();
    static constexpr result_type max();

private:
    using Twister = std::conditional_t<sizeof(T) <= 4, std::mt19937, std::mt19937_64>;
    Twister engine_;
};

// Class is implemented here, but these details don't matter for this answer; 
// see the link if interested
#endif
```

This class will only instantiate if the template type is unsigned, and based on the size of the unsigned type, the type of `engine_` will be either a 32-bit or 64-bit Mersenne Twister PRNG. It can also be said to be using an adapter pattern. Many of the other declarations outside the default constructor exist so that this class still works with the `<random>` library.

* Shameless self-plug